# Will this algorithm accumulate truncation error?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, floating-accuracy, nosql

I plan on writing a 3rd party script that allows a rating system for a webpage, but I only want each web page it's embedded on to take up one row in a database (or more accurately one document since I'm taking the NoSQL route). My pseudocode for rating will look like this:

```
function update(page, rate) {
  collection.get({
    page: page
  }, function callback(err, doc) {
    if (!err) {
      var rating = doc.rating,
        votes = doc.votes;

      collection.update({
        page: page
      }, {
        votes: votes + 1,
        rating: (rating * votes + rate) / (votes + 1) // here's the iffy part
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Is there a way to improve the algorithm in order to avoid truncation error for floating point values, or will this not be a problem in the first place?

Comment: Aren't all JS numbers floating point?

Comment: Yes they are... I'm asking if this program would accumulate truncation error over time since it multiplies the average and divides the total every time an update occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to improve the algorithm in order to avoid truncation error for floating point values, or will this not be a problem in the first place?

Yes. Store the sum of all ratings and the number of ratings as integers in the database, and only calculate the average from these when you go to display it.